# C# split three items in a distinct select list to display each item in a table (and add a link)

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach, split

I have a model, items. For a given customer I have a distinct list based on three field values. Next, I need to split the list (not return just the list) so that I can use one of the fields in an Html Action to link to another view (or return related results.

I can get the distinct list. This works fine. I get the expected list.

```
   @foreach (var it in Model.item.Select(y => y.orderno + " " + y.book + " " + y.year).Distinct())
    {        
        { <tr>
                <td width="25%">@Html.DisplayFor(model => it)</td>

                <td></td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
```

But I need to split the items (after I get the distinct values) and be able to use "orderno" to pass a link to another view.

When I get the distinct list, I only get the group (what I asked for). I don't know how to split the list. I have tried Split(',') in more variations than this one. It didn't work for me (likely my mistakes).

```
@foreach (var it in Model.item.Select(y => y.item.orderno + " " + y.item.book + " " + y.item.year).Distinct().ToList())
   {   
   List<string> result = it.Split(',').ToList();
      {
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">@Html.DisplayFor(model => it)</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The split method takes the character that you want to split your list on. In your example you were splitting on the comma character. Where you should be splitting by space.

```
@foreach (var it in Model.item.Select(y => y.item.orderno + " " + y.item.book + " " +      y.item.year).Distinct().ToList())
{   
    List<string> result = it.Split(' ').ToList();
    {
    <tr>
        <td width="25%">@Html.DisplayFor(model => it)</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: So what am I missing to be able to display the resulting values separately --- formatted in a table or a ul / dl list? The current code shows each row nicely, all three values in one column :( To act on the orderno value, I need it separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split by *space* not  *comma*.

```
var result = it.Split();
```

Also, `Split` already returns an array,so `ToList` call is redundant

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
@foreach (var it in Model.item.Select(y => y.orderno + "," + y.book + "," + y.year).Distinct())
{
    var result = it.Split(','); // result will be array
}
```